# Angular - Unknown Provider from Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-service

I have the strange issue, that somehow my own provider is not injecting correctly into my app.

This is my provider:

```
    angular.module '1425App'
    .provider 'OData',[() ->
      @_baseUrl = ''
      return {
        setBaseUrl: (value) ->
          @_baseUrl = value
          return
        $get: ['$http', '$q', ($http, $q) ->
          return {
          getAll: (resource) ->
            dfd = $q.defer()
            $http.get("#{@_baseUrl}/#{resource}").success (res) ->
              console.log res
              dfd.resolve()
              return
            return dfd.promise
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

This is my app + config block:

```
angular.module('1425App', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router',
  'angular-loading-bar',
  'ngAnimate',
  'toaster',
  'ui.gravatar',
  'ngFitText',
  'google-maps',
  'mm.foundation',
  'restangular',
  'ui.select2',
  'ngTable',
  'ngGrid',
  'ngCsv',
  'ui.date',
  'ngDragDrop',
  'ui.sortable'
])
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider, baseUrl, ODataProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor')

  ODataProvider.setBaseUrl(baseUrl + '/odata/')
  cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false
...
```

Im getting following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   1425App due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   ODataProvider

This leads to my believe, that its an issue with injecting the provider into my app. Any idea what im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at you pasted snippet issue could be that you have config block appearing before `oData` provider has been registered. Try setting up the config block after the oDataProvider registration.

Separate out config block from app registration and load it after your provider(s) have been registered. You can only configure the providers that are registered before the specific config block that uses it. This is not the case with `constant` though you can have them registered in any order.

The above information (which was a bug) is as of 1.2.* version of angular, with 1.3 you can register providers even after the config block.

Comment: @mlang You are welcome. If you upgrade to 1.3 rc you should not face this issue.